# VSCode Runs Wrong Prelaunch Task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

In my launch.json file I have defined a "preLaunchTask"  for the "Python Attach" configuration - here is an excerpt

```
{
            "name": "Python Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",            
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                   "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app/mount"
                }
            ],
            "port": 5678,
            "host": "127.0.0.1",            
            "preLaunchTask": {
                "task": "Integration",
                "type": "docker-compose",
                "label": "Integration"                               
            }          
        }
```

My tasks.json file has two task definitions using different docker files:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Integration",
            "type": "docker-compose",                     
            "dockerCompose": {
                "up": {
                    "detached": true,
                    "build": true,                    
                },
                "files": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/docker-compose.debug.yml"
                ],                
            }     
        },              
        {
            "label": "Prod",
            "type": "docker-compose",            
            "dockerCompose": {
                "up": {
                    "detached": true,
                    "build": true,                    
                },
                "files": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}/docker-compose.yml"
                ],                
            }     
        }        
    ]
}
```

When I run the project with the "Python Attach" configuration the "Prod" task is being used instead of the "Integration" task.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems with the preLaunchTask one can define in-line task definitions. That's not what I wanted. By just using the task-name the correct task is being executed.

Instead of:

```
"preLaunchTask": {
                "task": "Integration",
                "type": "docker-compose",
                "label": "Integration"                               
            }
```

I use:

```
"preLaunchTask": "Integration"
```